# Need to create a secure sign up page in ruby on rails, where do I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I need to create a secure sign up/login page for my website. I am coding in Ruby on Rails.

I don't know the first thing about doing this. I can create a simple sign up page, but how do I make sure that it is a secure page? I.e. I want the login/signup page to have a https://... URL (properly signed and whatnot).

What all do I need to do to go about this? Is there some way to make this process as easy as possible in ruby (i.e. is there some gem that allows for HTTPS logins/signups)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement this yourself. There are a couple of gems to help you do that. 
I use Devise, here's a simple howto http://blazingcloud.net/2011/01/08/devise-authentication-in-rails-3/
If you'd like to handle Facebook, twitter, openId and more, I recommend using Omniauth, it works well with devise.
Here is a tutorial to help you get started 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: awesome thanks for the info. We might go with AuthLogic & omniauth - what do you think of that??

Comment: Never tried AuthLogic, can you tell me why you are considering them?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is not an issue for your signup page, you'll have to purchase the certificate and run your server appropriately.

Devise is one of many great gems to use for authentication in rails but you should absolutely learn what's going on in the background before you start using one them. You should start with a tutorial on how an authentication system works. [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://%20railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top) is the best IMHO. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sorcery is the easier and more modular option. I totally recommend it over Devise.

https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery

There is a recent Railscast.